# why i got this error while moving object in spritekit

Tags: swift, skspritenode

I am trying make a game something like Tower defense. I am adding units to my map and I want to try movepoint to another point.

My code is:

```
func setTheNode(position:[Int],speed:[Int]){
        let moveDown1 = SKAction.moveToY(300, duration:4)
        let moveRight1 = SKAction.moveToX(300, duration: 3)

        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveDown1, moveRight1]);
        self.runAction(sequence)

    }
```

This works, however I want to read these position and durations from parameters.
When I try this way:

```
     func setTheNode(position:[Int],speed:[Int]){
                let moveDown1 = SKAction.moveToY(position[0], duration:speed[0])
                let moveRight1 = SKAction.moveToY(position[1], duration:speed[1])
            let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveDown1, moveRight1]);
            self.runAction(sequence)
}
```

I ger the error:

> Cannot invoke 'moveToY' with an argument list of type '(Int, duration:
>   Int)'

I also tried

```
let moveDown1 = SKAction.moveToY(position[0] as? Int, duration:speed[0] as? Int)
```

And got the same error again. Could you help me on this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SKAction.moveToY` accept a `CGFloat` for Y and an `NSTimeInterval` for `duration`. Therefore you need to change `position`'s type to `[CGFloat]` and `speed`'s type to `[NSTimeInterval]`.

There are a few other things I notice with your code:

**1.** I think it's a typo - you've written `let moveRight1 = SKAction.moveToY` in your second function. Should that be `SKAction.moveToX`?

**2.** You're using `speed` to represent time. That's going to give you some strange results because speed and time are inversely proportional. Therefore, with your implementation, if you increase `speed` it's going to take longer for your node to move...

I would recommend writing your function like so:

```
func setTheNode(deltaPosition dp: CGVector, times: (x: NSTimeInterval, y: NSTimeInterval)){
    let moveDown1  = SKAction.moveToY(dp.dx, duration: times.x)
    let moveRight1 = SKAction.moveToX(dp.dy, duration: times.y)

    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveDown1, moveRight1]);
    self.runAction(sequence)
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck with your project :)